# Uploaded but not moved. Why? Where is the uploaded file?

Tags: php, html, forms

Here is my php code trying to upload and move an image.  I am running it on my laptop.
The image seems to be loading (i get  "exists and was uploaded successfully.").  But the move_uploaded_file() is not moving the file, i cannot even find it.
I have changed directory permissions ... without positive results.
What directory permissions must i have? Assuming that's the issue.

```
<?php
// upload.php
echo <<<_END
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>PHP Form Upload</title></head>
<body>
<form method='post' action='upload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='10' />
<input type='submit' value='Upload' />
</form>
_END;

if ($_FILES)
{
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
    $theerror = $_FILES['filename']['error'];
    if(file_exists($temp)){
    if(is_uploaded_file($temp)) echo "$temp exists and was uploaded successfully.<br />";
        else echo "$temp exists, but not successfully uploaded. <br />";
        echo "Error code $theerror . <br />";        
    }
    else echo "$temp do not exists. <br />";
    $upload_dir = "/uploads";
    if(move_uploaded_file($temp,  $upload_dir . "/" . $name)) 
        echo "Uploaded image '$upload_dir/$name' <br /> <img src='$upload_dir/$name' />";
    else 
        echo "$temp wasn't moved, why? <br />";
}

echo "</body></html>";
?>
```

Comment: On a point of style: use braces around all your conditional code and indent consistently. That way program flow is much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a path relative to the web-root, not to the file-system.

Change:

```
$upload_dir = "/uploads";
```

to something like:

```
$upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/uploads";
```

You should also take care to clean the `$_FILES['filename']['name']` variable to avoid uploads with names like `../../../../passwd`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (isset($_FILES['filename'])) {
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];

    $upload_dir = "uploads";

    if (move_uploaded_file($temp, $upload_dir . "/" . $name))
        echo "Uploaded image '$upload_dir/$name' <br /> <img src='$upload_dir/$name' />";
    else
        echo "{$name} wasn't moved, why? <br />";
}
```